# parsing json objects with arrays in swift

Tags: ios, swift, json.net

I have this JsonResponse:

```
...id = 7;
levels =     (
            {
        name = "name";
        "unique_id" = 23223;
    },
            {
        name = "name";
        "unique_id" = d32432;
    },
            {
        name = "name";
        "unique_id" = 324;
    },
            {
        name = "name";
        "unique_id" = 234;
    }
);
```

I am using this to get result as a dictionary:

```
var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as! NSDictionary
```

MY question is how can i parse the levels array - iterating the objects and getting the array size

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just loop through them:

```
if(jsonResult)
{
   let levels = jsonResult! as NSDictionary;

    for item in levels {
        let obj = item as NSDictionary

        let name = obj["name"] as NSString;
        let uniqueId = obj["unique_id"] as NSNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what is "levels" in your example how do i get it from my jsonResult?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use type safety as much as you can when using JSON. Here is an (untested) example to show you how you can cast safely the data:

```
if let levels = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    for elem in levels {
        let name = elem["name"] as? NSString
        let uniqueId = elem["unique_id"] as? NSNumber

    }
}
```